# Como aterar a % para inteiro em charts google

Tags: php, mysql, google-charts

Tenho esse chart:
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na parte visivel esta a porcentagem,como eu faço para alterar a porcentagem pelo quantidade inteira:

Exemplo:

Como mostra na imagem em anexo ao invés de aparecer 14.3% mostrar 1.

Segue meu código:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSetores);


      function drawSetores() {


        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
        <?php
        $setores = mysql_query("SELECT  
        distinct sol_setor AS ID,
        st.setor_nome AS SETOR,
        CONCAT(count(s.sol_setor)) AS QUANT
        FROM
         solicitacao AS s 
         INNER JOIN  setor  AS st ON s.sol_setor = st.setor_id
         GROUP BY sol_setor");
         while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($setores)) {
            echo "['$r[1]', $r[2]],\n";
        }
        ?>
        ]);

        // Set options for Sarah's pie chart.
        var options = {title:'SETORES',
                       width:550,
                       height:300,
                       is3D:true};

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Setores'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

Comment: Oi Otácio, legal a pergunta, valeu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione em `option` a propriedade `pieSliceText : 'value'`

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work', 11],
          ['Eat', 2],
          ['Commute', 2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep', 7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          pieSliceText: 'value'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Nas [opções](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options) do PieChart, você pode configurar o `pieSliceText` da seguinte forma:

- 'percentage' - A porcentagem da fatia em relação ao total.
- 'value' - O valor quantitativo da fatia.
- 'label' - O nome da fatia.
- 'none' - Nenhum texto.

> também preciso colocar R$ e transformar em decimal é possivel ?

Sim, basta adicionar antes do método `draw` o `formatter`:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({decimalSymbol: ',',groupingSymbol: '.', negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true, prefix: 'R$ '});
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 1123121],
    ['Eat', 3123212],
    ['Commute', 213212],
    ['Watch TV', 123122],
    ['Sleep', 1231237]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities',
    pieSliceText: 'value'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    decimalSymbol: ',',
    groupingSymbol: '.',
    negativeColor: 'red',
    negativeParens: true,
    prefix: 'R$ '
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Perfeito,Obrigado.

Comment: Adicionei os valores para a propriedade, @OtácioBarbosa.

Comment: Faz parte também do que eu preciso, também preciso colocar R$ e transformar em decimal é possivel ?

Comment: Você quer mostrar valores monetários no lugar da porcentagem e/ou inteiro?

Comment: sim,e se possivel incluir a sigla R$

Comment: Sim, é possível. Editei a resposta e inclui, @OtácioBarbosa.

Comment: Ótimo. Mais uma vez Obrigado.